# Speed difference in Python compiled with MS C vs. MinGW

Tags: python, c, windows, gcc, mingw-w64

On my Windows 7 machine, I use two CPython implementations:

1) [WinPython distribution](http://winpython.sourceforge.net/), which is compiled with MSC v.1500 64bit

2) [MinGW-builds](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/), which is compiled with MinGW/GCC 4.9.1 64bit

I've tried the MinGW-built version to compile some C extensions for Python, which need to be built with the same compiler as Python itself to function properly.
Now consider the following test script, which generates a random dictionary and repeatedly pickles&unpickles it.

```
import pickle, cPickle, random
from time import clock

def timeit(mdl, d, num=100, bestof=10):
    times = []
    for _ in range(bestof):
        start = clock()
        for _ in range(num):
            mdl.loads(mdl.dumps(d))
        times.append(clock() - start)
    return min(times)

def gen_dict(entries=100, keylength=5):
    formatstr = "{:0%dx}" % keylength
    d = {}
    for _ in range(entries):
        rn = random.randrange(16**keylength) # 'keylength'-digit hex number
        # format into string of length 5 as key, decimal value as value
        d[formatstr.format(rn)] = rn
    return d

def main(entries=100, keylength=5, num=100, bestof=10):
    print "Dict size: %d entries, keylength: %d" % (entries, keylength)
    print ("Test is %d times pack/unpack. "
           "Take best time out of %d runs\n" % (num, bestof))
    d = gen_dict(entries, keylength)
    for mdl in [pickle, cPickle]:
        print "%s: %f s" % (mdl.__name__, timeit(mdl, d, num, bestof))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

MSC CPython gave me

```
Dict size: 100 entries, keylength: 5
Test is 100 times pack/unpack. Take best time out of 10 runs

pickle: 0.107798 s
cPickle: 0.011802 s
```

and MinGW/GCC CPython gave me

```
Dict size: 100 entries, keylength: 5
Test is 100 times pack/unpack. Take best time out of 10 runs

pickle: 0.103065 s
cPickle: 0.075507 s
```

So the cPickle module (a standard library C extension for Python) is 6.4x slower on MinGW than on MSC.
I haven't investigated further (i.e. tested more C extensions), but I am quite surprised.
Is this to be expected?
Will other C extensions run in general slower on a Python/MinGW toolchain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used MSYS2 and the MinGW-w64 tool chain to compile a large CPU-bound extension. It did not run unusually slow; I actually think it runs faster than MSC. One possible cause for slow extensions: the `Mingw32CCompiler` class contained in the file `cygwincompiler.py` specified `-O` optimization. I changed that to `-O2` and the performance improved.

I use the extension with the standard CPython as distributed from python.org.

**Update**

I tried your sample program on MSYS2. There are two versions of Python 2.7 available: one that is part of the MSYS2 distribution and the other is part of the MinGW-w64 tool-chain. The version that is included with MSYS2 does not exhibit the performance issue while the version included with MinGW-w64 does exhibit the performance issue with cPickle. Since the MSYS2 version is compiled by the GCC included in MinGW-w64, I believe the slowdown is related to the specific options used when compiling the MinGW version. I haven't looked at the source code for both versions to see what causes the difference.

Regarding the requirement to use the same version of the compiler for an extension as the Python interpreter - the answer is "It depends....". The problem occurs because there are some minor differences between the C runtime library that is used by each major version of MSC. IIRC, one of the differences can break the passing of file handles between Python and the extension. If you don't use any calls that rely on the differences, then you can mix compiler versions. Since there isn't a definitive list of differences, nor a way to prevent an extension from making those calls that are different, the only guaranteed answer is not mixing versions. My extension doesn't (I think) use any C runtime calls that are different. It only uses the Python C-API for all IO and memory management. I have successfully mixed compiler versions when testing but I still prefer not to do so.

I'm still experimenting with the MSYS2/MinGW-w64 approach to building my extension and using it with an MSC-compiled version of CPython. It does appear to work and it performs as expected.

Comment: The versions from python.org are AFAIK all compiled with MSC. So you are not using a CPython version compiled with MinGW, right? This would not contradict the results above. Is it never a problem to use different compilers for Python than for the extensions?

Comment: @Pybe I've expanded my answer.

Comment: You are right! The MSYS2 version is up to speed. Thanks for pointing me there.